# how to output gif with same size as input video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am following [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality)

It gives example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

However I want the gif output to be the same size as video and not 320 as specified here so I removed `scale=320:-1` so I have

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

When I run that I get:

```
No such filter: 'flags' Error initializing complex filters.
```

If I remove:

```
-filter_complex "fps=10,flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse"
```

Then it works but quality of the video is bad. So it seems that I must use a scale for those palette flags to work, how can I get ffmpeg to output gif same size as input video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Omit the scale filter

By default the output uses the same width and height as the input. The `:flags=lanczos` was part of the scale filter. So your command will look like:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" out.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

> ffmpeg -i video.mkv -y -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=iw:ih:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output_mkv.gif

scale=iw:ih does the trick, same size as input video